# Is human person really and absolutely free?

Tags: ethics, human-condition, reason, freedom

Is a human really and absolutely free? When can we say that they are free?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! This question is a little broad for our format. Please have a look at the help center and the tour. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour. Questions here should ideally be answerable in a few paragraphs and not invite discussion.

Comment: There are already many questions on freedom in this site with answers. Like https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10432, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37432, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36639 . So it would help if you could explain your question based on the existing answers.

Comment: I think it would help to narrow your focus to at least a school of philosophy, if not a particular pihlosopher

Comment: Short answer: No. Check out [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: Free Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freewill/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is a human really and absolutely free?

No. As a body (if he thinks he is an embodiment of Body, Mind and Intellect) he is never really and absolutely free.

> When can we say that they are free?

We cannot say so. But he/she can say/feel so (with confirmation) only when he realizes his real nature.  Then he/she can say he/she (the self) is absolutely free.